# Replace values in a subset of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's suppose I have this:

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[1:3, ]
dt[wt == 2.620, "am"] <- 4
dt[wt == 2.620,]
```

My output is:

```
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  4    4    4
```

I want to replace the value `4` by `0` only in the columns `gear` and `carb`.

The final data would look like this:

```
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  4    0    0
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can just do `dt[carb==4] <- 0`, and `dt[gear==4] <- 0`, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @HenryRice - I don't think the OP wants to update every value in the row

Comment: @SymbolixAU Good call, forgot that you have to specify the column directly to avoid overwriting the whole row.

Comment: `dt[ws == 2.620, c('gear','carb') := .(0, 0)]` will do what you probably want, the way data.table intends it to be done.

Comment: @Jealie - unless the requirement is also that `gear == 4 | carb == 4`

Comment: You would do it in two lines `dt[wt == 2.62 & gear == 4, gear := 0]` and  `dt[wt == 2.62 & carb == 4, carb := 0]`. Don't worry, it's still very efficient because you are updating by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your small example, the method proposed by @HenryRice is sufficient (with maybe a further subset where `wt == 2.62`).

If you were doing it on more rows or columns, using `data.table`'s `for` / `set` loop would be useful in this scenario

```
for(j in c("gear", "carb"))
    set(dt, i = which(dt[[j]] == 4 & dt[["wt"]] == 2.620), j = j, value = 0)

dt
#     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  4    0    0
# 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
dt$carb[dt$carb==4] <- 0
dt$gear[dt$gear==4] <- 0
```

Comment: I also think the OP wants the 0s in only the rows where `wt == 2.620`

Comment: Using `<-` for assignment misses one of the best values of a `data.table`: fast updates by reference instead of copying.